# extend activity from another to retrieve image from firebase storage to firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to get a selected image uri into my cart database. I have tried to extend an activity from another, but I wasn't sure, and I got an error. here is where I stored all products in ProductActivity.

```
private void SaveProductInfoToDatabase()
    {
ProductsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Products");
...
        HashMap<String, Object> productMap = new HashMap<>();
        productMap.put("description", Description);
        productMap.put("image", downloadImageUrl);
        productMap.put("price", Price);
        productMap.put("pname", Pname);
```

here is what I did to get image in the other activity

```
.
.
final DatabaseReference cartMap = new HashMap<>();

        cartMap.put("pname", productName.getText().toString());
        cartMap.put("price", productPrice.getText().toString());
       cartMap.put("image", SellerAddNewProductActivity.downloadImageUrl);
}
```

I got this error in both activities:

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference.

Can someone help me please? I am still learning.

Comment: If the error comes from the code you shared, it seems that `productName.getText()` or `productPrice.getText()` is `null`, and you can't call `null.toString()`. A typical way to fix this problem is to check `if (productName.getText() != null) cartMap.put("pname", productName.getText().toString());`, but I recommend reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: my code works completely fine before I extend the activity to get image in the DB. now I am getting errors. are there any alternative on how to get this images in my Cart List database ?